# Create a VBA Excel Macro to Copy Cells to another sheet based on Primary ID Match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to automatically copy and paste cells using a VBA Macro based on conditions.

I've tried to use a VLOOKUP and MATCH function, as well as some VBA code used to copy cells, I just can't seem to achieve what i'm after.

My objective is to copy some cells from Sheet1(LMSData) and Sheet2(Schedule) to another sheet (Learning Roster) where Unique ID in [LMSData!A2:A] = Person ID in [Schedule!B2:BA]

If there is a match (or multiple matches), I want to copy Competency Name and Expiry Date from LMS Data to Sheet3(LearningRoster) as well as PersonID, Start Date, Start Time and Finish Time from Schedule to Learning Roster.

Images to the sheets mentioned above can be found here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFoNH.jpg - LMSData

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3lDc.jpg - Schedule

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRpnt.jpg - LearningRoster

I would greatly appreciate any help, or being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: So what code have you got? then people may offer corrections or improvements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script for this work.

I have considered column(Competency Name, Expiry Date, Person ID) in LMSData Sheet and column(Person ID, Start Date, Start Time, Finish Time) for Schedule Sheet.

You can modify data type based on your requirement

Below are the steps performed:

1. Pick Person ID from Schedule sheet.
2. Filter LMSData sheet with personid and copy visible record into temporary sheet.
3. Copy all this record into Learning Roster sheet.

'Sub copyData()

```
Dim PersonId, StartDate, StartTime, FinishTime, CompentencyName, ExpiryDate, CompetencyName As String
Dim ScheduleIndex, TempIndex, LearningRosterIndex As Integer

ScheduleIndex = 2
LearningRosterIndex = 2

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Cells(ScheduleIndex, 1).Value <> ""
    PersonId = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Cells(ScheduleIndex, 1).Value
    StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Cells(ScheduleIndex, 2).Value
    StartTime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Cells(ScheduleIndex, 3).Value
    FinishTime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule").Cells(ScheduleIndex, 4).Value
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LMSData")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:C100000")
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(PersonId), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("A1")
        End With
    End With
    TempIndex = 2
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(TempIndex, 1).Value <> ""
        CompetencyName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(TempIndex, 1).Value
        ExpiryDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(TempIndex, 2).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LearningRoster").Cells(LearningRosterIndex, 1).Value = PersonId
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LearningRoster").Cells(LearningRosterIndex, 2).Value = StartDate
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LearningRoster").Cells(LearningRosterIndex, 3).Value = StartTime
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LearningRoster").Cells(LearningRosterIndex, 4).Value = FinishTime
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LearningRoster").Cells(LearningRosterIndex, 5).Value = CompetencyName
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LearningRoster").Cells(LearningRosterIndex, 6).Value = ExpiryDate
        LearningRosterIndex = LearningRosterIndex + 1
        TempIndex = TempIndex + 1
    Loop

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Range("A1:C10000").ClearContents

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LMSData")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:C100000")
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    End With
    ScheduleIndex = ScheduleIndex + 1
Loop
```

End Sub
`